# In Python, what would be a single, compact method to convert an int, a float or unicode to a string?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, int, encode

I have a very large number of database objects from SQLite3 to loop over and to print to terminal. I'm trying to have a robust method that can be applied to every object retreived from the database such that it is converted to a string. The objects are likely to be strings, ints, floats and unicode.

My initial approach was to simply use the function `str()` on every object, but this fails on some unicode. I was prompted then to try to use `.encode("utf-8")` on every object, but this fails on ints (`'int' object has no attribute 'encode'`). What would be a compact way to try to convert these objects to strings?

The best I've got right now is something like the following:

```
try:
    string_representation = str(row[column])
except:
    string_representation = str(row[column].encode("utf-8"))
row_contents.append(string_representation)
```

Is there a better, perhaps more compact approach? A one-liner would be nice.

Comment: @ravenspoint I'm using the [dataset](https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to interact with an SQLite3 database, but I don't think this matters particularly; I already have retrieved objects from the database and I'm trying to convert them to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `unicode()` on the numeric values.

But if you have a collection that includes both unicode string and byte strings, and you want to avoid any implicit encoding, you would have to check the types.

Answer (score 0):

In C you would call

const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);

which will return whatever converted to text

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html

Dunno what you would do in python - it is better to use the database engine for these things = faster and more reliable.